# Animating content newly added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-animate

I am working on the front end of a web application. All of the content is generated from JSON objects that I receive from the back end. I then wrap this content in HTML and add it to the DOM. I do this using jQuery append(). Once the content is added I animate the old page out and the new page in.

My problem is that the content does not seem to finish loading before the animation starts. It also seems that not all of my CSS takes effect before the animation starts. It only shows once the animation is done.

I assumed that I need to check if the content is finished appending before I start animating. I know that append() is supposed to be synchronous, but is could not hurt to check.

Here is a code snippet to give you an idea of the animation involved. (note: this is not all of my code, only a bare minimum to give you an idea of what exactly I am doing)

- 'mainTransitionContainer' is the element to which the new content was added.
- 'transitionWidth' is a variable that is determined using the width of both the old and the new page.
- Both these pages are inside of mainTransitionContainer, floating next to each other.

> ```
> $(mainTransitionContainer).append(newElement);
> $(mainTransitionContainer).ready(function () {
>    $(mainTransitionContainer).animate({ right: transitionWidth }, 2000,'easeInOutQuart'});
> });
> ```

Is this the correct way to check if the content is finished loading?

Does anyone have another idea why my content is not showing correctly?

Is the jQuery animation perhaps effecting my CSS styles?

Does anyone have any advice? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How do you load the content ? The `ready` event only works with the `document` as it binds a handler to the DOMReady event, which is not fired when you load content via async requests.

Comment: Thanks Didier. That already clarifies things a bit. I have edited the original code to give you a better idea. The 'newElement' variable is basically a string containing some complex HTML code. This is then added to 'mainTransitionContainer' using append().

Comment: How is *generated* `newElement` content ? Loaded via ajax or simply build up in javascript ?

Comment: At the moment I am still is the testing phase, so I simply build a long string. The content shows partly before the animation, and entirely after. The problem is that I only see part of my content during the animation. If I try with less content, it works perfectly.

Comment: Could you put an example up on JSFiddle? Where animation is concerned, it's much easier to see exactly what's going on/wrong with a slightly more detailed test case including the HTML+CSS for `mainTransitionContainer` and `newElement`.

Comment: Is there something similar to .ready() that I can use? I tried .load(), but it never fires.

Comment: The point that Didier tried to make previously is that you don't need to use `.ready()` (or similar) when injecting content using `.append()`. 

This is because, as you rightly said in your question, it is a *synchronous* method, and will never fire a `ready` event. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jimmed/kdXPh/) to see how you might achieve it.

If your content is taking a long time to appear, it may be possible that there's something iffy about the way you're generating your HTML. Either way, a fiddle would be helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks Jim. I'll try to do so. This is part of a much larger application though, and the entire front end is upwards of 5000 lines of code so far...

Comment: Hi all. Thanks you all for your willingness to help. On your suggestion, I rewrote the code to show you only the parts I am having trouble with. In doing so I realized that I was doing something else wrong. The content is in fact being added synchronously before the animation starts. The size and complexity of the DOM object being added does not seem to influence the time it takes to append. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that I was making a mistake elsewhere. The issue has been resolved. The content is being added synchronously, and thus no event needs to be triggered when the content is done being appended.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, if you are loading data using JSON, you are using Ajax calls to retrieve the data?

You cannot really use the `.ready()` function here. This will be triggered when the page has loaded initially, regardless of any Ajax calls that could happen afterwards. It basically fires whenever the intended element idles (i.e. it has been changed, and the first moment the changes are complete and no code is run, the `ready` trigger will fire)

I don't know how your ajax call is structured as I see no snippet in your question, but this is a rough sketch of what you should to in order to maintain the 'load, write, then animate' structure you want:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "http://my.url.com",

    type: 'get', //I assume. It could be 'post' dependent on what the code behind does.

    cache: false, //for good measure. IE will never execute the same request twice, unless you put this in.

    success: function(data_in_json_form) {

        var data_in_html_form = .... //Do something with the received data_in_json_form. You need to end up with a string of valid html code.

        $(mainTransitionContainer).append(data_in_html_form);

        //Now you can do the animation.
        $(mainTransitionContainer).animate({ right: transitionWidth }, 2000,'easeInOutQuart'});

    }

});
```

The important things to remember are:

- Any code that is not in the 'success' function will be executed without requiring the ajaxt call to have completed. Ajax works asynchronously, so the browser starts the ajax request, and then carries on without waiting for a response.
- Append does work synchronously. However, when used in combination with Ajax calls, make sure to executes the code only in the 'success' function.
- The `.ready()` trigger should really only be used for `$(document).ready()`. It might work in other scenarios, but it it almost never the right solution to a problem.

This is what I make of the issue you are describing. If I am missing something, please post more code, specifically of your JSON retrieval method and any code following it.